# Error "Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\biservis\profil.php on line 199 "

Tags: codeigniter

My English is bad sorry my code error :

```
$goster = mysqli_query($mysqlicon, 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS yayinlar FROM yayin');
$sonuc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($goster);
```

Page Navigation Code:

```
$sayfada = 5; 
$goster = mysqli_query($mysqlicon, 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS yayinlar FROM yayin');
$sonuc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($goster);
$toplam_icerik = $sonuc['yayin'];
$toplam_sayfa = ceil($toplam_icerik / $sayfada);
$sayfa = isset($_GET['s']) ? (int) $_GET['s'] : 1;
if($sayfa < 1) $sayfa = 1; 
if($sayfa > $toplam_sayfa) $sayfa = $toplam_sayfa; 

$limit = ($sayfa - 1) * $sayfada;
$sorgugst = mysqli_query($mysqlicon, "SELECT * FROM yayinlar LIMIT  $limit, $sayfada");

while($icerik = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sorgugst)) {

$sorguyayin = mysqli_query($mysqlicon, "SELECT * FROM yayinlar WHERE uye_id='$uye_id' ORDER BY id DESC");


if(0==$numrows){
echo "Hünüz Bir Yayın Paylaşmadınız. Yukarıdan birşeyler paylaşmayı deneyin!";
}else{

while($kayit=mysqli_fetch_array($sorguyayin)) { 


?>

<div class="yayinla">
<div class="yayinci">
<div class="yay-ad">Yayıncı Adı: <?php echo "$adi" ?></div>
<div class="yay-hiz">Verdiği Hizmet: <?php echo "$verilen_hizmet" ?></div>
<div class="yay-hiz">Yayın Tarihi: <?php echo "$yayin_tarihi" ?></div>
<div class="edit">
<div class="duzenle"><!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a  href="yayin-duzenle?id=<?php echo $kayit["id"]; ?>">
<img src="images/duzenle.png" alt="Düzenle" />
</a>
</div>
<div class="sil">
<a  href="yayin-sil?id=<?php echo $kayit["id"]; ?>">
<img src="images/cop.png" alt="Çöp" />
</a>
</div>
<div class="temizle"></div>
</div>
<div class="temizle"></div>
</div>
<div class="icerik">
<div class="profil-resmi"><img src="<?php echo "$firma_logolari"; ?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
<div class="yayin"><?php echo $kayit["yayin"]; ?>
</div>
<div class="temizle"></div>
</div>
<div class="temizle"></div>
</div>
<div class="temizle"></div>
<?php } }}

for($s = 1; $s <= $toplam_sayfa; $s++) {
if($sayfa == $s) { // eğer bulunduğumuz sayfa ise link yapma.
echo $s . ' '; 
} else {
echo '<a href="?s=' . $s . '">' . $s . '</a> ';
}
}
```

Comment: please at least format your code a bit and phrase your question better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be used `CI query builder`  for these queries

Queries should be like this :

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS yayinlar FROM yayin');
if ($query->num_rows() > 0 {
    $query->row()->yayinlar;
}


$sayfada = 5; 
$limit = ($sayfa - 1) * $sayfada;
...........
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM yayinlar LIMIT  $limit, $sayfada");
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['field_name'];
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html